# apache - how to override index of /icons?

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp

I wasn't aware of this, and it is kind of funny; when you name a directory **icons** in the root of your host, then if you point your browser to host.com/icons, apache does not read from that directory and shows you a listing of *Public Domain Icons*.

I added an *icons* directory to the root and placed a key.png file in that directory, yet accessing that image results in 404. I tried to find if/where this has been documented and how it could be turned off. I found nothing. Could someone provide a pointer?

P.S. I am using XAMPP 1.7.3 which basically is a WAMP and has Apache 2.2.14

Edit
Aparently lots of live servers have this turned on and **index of /icons** could be seen [lots of places](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=%2Ficons&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=url&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl#as_qdr=all&q=%22Index%20of%20%2Ficons%22).

Comment: Thanks for posting this @Majid. I was caught out when I moved a website to a new hosting company and they were stumped for 4 hours until I found this post. They couldn't easily amend their standard server build so I had to rename the folder and update my code to get my website working again! Not something you would expect to have to deal with at all! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd assume that you have an alias within your httpd.conf.

I'm not familiar with XAMPP's config files or their location (google suggests it's probably in \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) but I'd suggest you're looking for a line like the following:

```
Alias /icons/ /usr/local/apache/icons/
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html for more info.

EDIT:
According to [XMAPP site](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#configfiles), you need to check `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and the `extra` subfolder.

Comment: Ok, can you search for 'icons' within any of the files in \xampp\apache\conf directory? Xampp might reference several config files.

Comment: I found it in extra/httpd-autoindex.conf. But it is somehow related to FancyIndexing and the comment above the Alias says `If  you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.` So commenting this might have unwanted consequences. I'd have to read what FancyIndexing is and besides commenting the alias out what else I should do. Thank again.

Answer (score 12):

Open this file: `%XAMPP_PATH%\apache\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf`

### and change :

```
Alias /icons/ "X:/xampp/apache/icons/"
<Directory "X:/xampp/apache/icons/">
```

---

### to this:

```
Alias /icons/ "./icons/"
<Directory "./icons/">
```

---

Restart your Apache Server.

Comment: If you find this alias unnecessary, simply comment this out from file <xampp installation>\apache\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf

Answer (score 2):

I would look in either your apache config file (\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) or your .htaccess files and see if there is a redirect going on.

**EDIT:** I think Grhm is correct in that an `Alias` is in your config file somewhere, per the XAMPP site:

> The main configuration file for Apache. It's including other files from the subdirectory "extra".

See if there is a directory called extra in the \xampp\apache\conf\ directory and then go through the files in there and see if that Alias is present.

Comment: Thanks. I have no .htaccess in the route, and didn't know redirects might be put in httpd.conf. I'd take a look.

Comment: Nope. httpd.conf does not contain the word `icons`.